# Invalid backups in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, backup

everyone:

We're using Neo4j in a we application and the server has an scheduled backup using neo4j-admin backup --backup-dir=/backup --name=neo4j --fallback-to-full

So far the backups are being done, we have a cron job to zip and copy these files to a versioned storage and everything seems to be working well. Last week we had a database problem (had to restart the server and the database never started again) so we had to resort to restore the backup. None of the existing backups were valid: file structure is OK, database mounts and starts and if you run a MATCH (n) RETURN COUNT(*) it says there are hundreds of thousands of elements, but not a single label, relationship, anything.

We've moved back and back until we found a backup that was valid. There were no issues that day, no restarts, no application errors, no traces in Neo4J logs, nothing. It simply started creating invalid backups from that day on with no complains. This is a scary case of silent failure that could bring big troubles in a production environment. Is there anyone facing a similar problem? I've searched and have not found any known issue, open ticket or similar in Neo4J. Please, advise...

Thank you very much...

Comment: Which version of Neo4j? Do you run consistency checks during backups (and if not, do you run the check separately on the backup afterwards)? Have you looked through the debug and neo4j logs? Looks like you're using enterprise edition, do you have a support account? If so create a ticket with us.